# Deploy liferay 6.1 on WAS 7.0

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, websphere-7, websphere-portal

I am trying to deploy Liferay 6.1 on [WAS 7.0](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp).

Though I have deployed it successfully with context path as "lportal", while accessing it I facing following issues

1. class not found

   > com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.invokerfilter
   >   exception

   Which was resolved somehow by restarting the server.

   Currently, I have portlet.jar, portal-service.jar, mysql.jar and hsql.jar in global    path i.e

   `IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ext folder`
2. Dockbar portlet is not loading up and showing only processing icon

   [image]

Has anyone tried this and access liferay from WAS successfully?

Any help is appriciated.